# What's a good name for the natural transformation `forall a. m a -> (Identity ⊕ m) a`?

Tags: haskell

I found myself writing a bunch of functions with the signature

```
a -> Either longComplicatedType (m longComplicatedType)
```

So I decided I needed an alias

```
type SomeAlias m a = Either a (m a)
```

making it just a natural transformation on the functor `m`, isomorphic to `forall a. m a -> (Identity ⊕ m) a`.

At first I was tempted to name it `MaybeN` or `MaybeF`, as it either used the functor `m` or nothing. But `Maybe a` is isomorphic to `1 ⊕ a`, and [`Identity` isn't the terminal object in the category of endofunctors, `Proxy` is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6317/is-the-identity-functor-the-terminal-object-of-the-category-of-endofunctors-on), so `MaybeN f a` should be `Either (Proxy a) (f a)`.

Is there an existing name for `forall a. m a -> (Identity ⊕ m) a` I can steal from somewhere else? Failing that, is there a more elegant name than `IdentityOr`?

Comment: `Succ`, since `Succ f = 1 + f` (just kidding).

Comment: `SomeAlias m` is a functor. Where is the natural transformation?

Comment: Why don't you use `EitherT`/`ErrorT` monad transformer?

Comment: Heimdall: if I used `EitherT`, I'd have to write `EitherT longComplicatedType m longComplicatedType`. No benefit.

Comment: n.m.: `SomeAlias` is the natural transformation `m ~> Identity ⊕ m`

Comment: A natural transformation is a polymorphic function. SomeAlias is a type.

Comment: `toSomeAlias :: m a -> SomeAlias m a; toSomeAlias = Right`

Comment: Yep that's one n.trans. of type `a -> SomeAlias m a`... but I think that should be a Left, for Right you also need something of type `a->m a`.

Comment: n.m.:  Look closer. `toSomeAlias` takes a `m a`, not an `a`, and `SomeAlias m a = Either a (m a)`.

Comment: Although `Identity` isn't the terminal object, [it is the monodial identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category).

Comment: Might I ask what you are working on?

Comment: I see the type-level S-combinator applied to `Either`.

Comment: user3237456: thanks! [that lead to this implementation](http://www.quora.com/Is-the-type-level-S-combinator-useful-in-Haskell).  `EssEither` is pretty descriptive.

Comment: PyRulez: a monad transformer that models computations that may or may not require side-effects in the underlying monad.

Comment: @rampion Inspired by the S-combinator thing, you could also use a type operator `type (f <*> g) a = f a (g a)`. This would be the type-level equivalent of `(<*>)` for the `(->) x` `Applicative` instance (since `(<*>)` for that instance is the S combinator). Unfortunately, you start to run into issues if you try to extend this further to work together with a type-level `(<$>)` (I think this is because of the "type synonyms must be fully applied" thing, but I got *much* weirder error messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for exists under the name [`Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html#Lift)

```
data Lift g a = Pure a | Other (g a)
```

This could be defined as a type synonym in terms of [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html#t:Sum) and [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity)

```
data Sum :: (k -> Type) -> (k -> Type) -> (k -> Type) where
  InL :: f a -> (Sum f g) a
  InR :: g a -> (Sum f g) a

newtype Identity :: Type -> Type where
  Identity :: a -> Identity a

type Lift g a = (Sum Identity g) a
```

but this will not give you an `Applicative` or `Alternative` instance.

`Sum f g` is only an applicative under very specific circumstances (given a monoidal natural transformation `forall xx. (Applicative g, Applicative f) => g xx -> f xx`) (more info: [*Abstracting with Applicatives*](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/) and [*Constructing Applicative Functors*](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Constructors.html)). This exists for

```
mnt :: forall xx. Applicative f => Identity xx -> f xx
mnt (Identity x) = pure x
```

and `Lift g` is that special case.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be isomorphic to `InR` from [`Data.Functor.Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html) with `f = Identity` and `g = m`:

> ```
> data Sum f g a = InL (f a) | InR (g a)
> ```

There was [quite a bit of bikeshedding](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2012-December/019140.html) when the libraries committee chose those names, however; you may find some other alternatives there.

Comment: This is [`Lift`][1], like `Sum Identity` but with more instances (`Applicative`, `Alternative`).


  [1]: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html#Lift

Comment: @Iceland_jack Huh, so it is. You should make your own answer.